# Aggregation with $limit , $match , $ne returns more documents than expected

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have two collection vmdetails and rsc_installtion_status , i want to select the documents from rsc_installtion_status which do not have matching hostname in vmdetails

I used the below query

```
 db.rsc_installtion_status.aggregate([{$lookup:{ from: "vmdetails",let: {rschostname: "$hostname"},pipeline:[{$match:{$expr:{$ne :["$hostname","$$rschostname"]}}}],as: "rscInstall"}},{$unwind:"$rscInstall"},{$project:{"_id":0,"rscInstall":0}}])
```

the no of records in vmdetails

```
> db.vmdetails.find().count()
4
```

the no of records in

```
> db.rsc_installtion_status.find().count()
37
```

out of 37 three documents match with documents in vmdetails so i expect the result to be 34 documents but the outcome what i get is 3 records for each document ie 34X3

```
{ "hostname" : "string", "configdownload" : "string", "rscpkgdownload" : "string", "configextraction" : "string", "rscpkgextraction" : "string", "rscstartup" : "string", "installedversion" : "string", "_class" : "com.mastercard.rsc.domain.RscInstalltionStatus" }
{ "hostname" : "string", "configdownload" : "string", "rscpkgdownload" : "string", "configextraction" : "string", "rscpkgextraction" : "string", "rscstartup" : "string", "installedversion" : "string", "_class" : "com.mastercard.rsc.domain.RscInstalltionStatus" }
{ "hostname" : "string", "configdownload" : "string", "rscpkgdownload" : "string", "configextraction" : "string", "rscpkgextraction" : "string", "rscstartup" : "string", "installedversion" : "string", "_class" : "com.mastercard.rsc.domain.RscInstalltionStatus" }
```

but in the $match if i use $eq instead of $ne the results are correct it only outputs three records. how can i select the records which do not match with hostname

Comment: Do you see the [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) in your aggregation pipeline? Please go read the documentation page and realize exactly what it does. Clearly you have just copied some code from somewhere without taking the time to understand what it is doing. i.e "More results are **expected**". Read and find out why.

Comment: @NeilLunn I know i am using unwind ,and also dont accept your comments " Clearly you have just copied some code from somewhere without taking the time to understand what it is doing"  I have done the query using with unwind and without unwind and have tried so many options after that only posting here for help

Comment: the query is based on the example here  https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/db.o

Comment: db.rsc_installtion_status.aggregate([
 {$lookup :
  {
    from:"vmdetails",
    localField:"hostname",
    foreignField:"hostname" ,
    as:"rscinstall"
  }
 },
  {
      $match: { "rscinstall": { $eq: [] } }
   }
 ])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
db.rsc_installtion_status.aggregate([ {$lookup : { from:"vmdetails", localField:"hostname", foreignField:"hostname" , as:"rscinstall" } }, { $match: { "rscinstall": { $eq: [] } } } ])
```

the lookup script is basic one the below match is the one which solved $eq which checks whether the array is empty or not and returns documents which are not common in both collections. if $ne used then it will return the records which are matched in both the collections.

```
{ $match: { "rscinstall": { $eq: [] } } } ])
```

Comment: Hi! while this answer may solve OP's problem, it is discouraged to post code only answers on SO. Providing some explanation will help OP understand this solution better, while also contributing to SO's mission of providing quality solutions to future users of the site. Thanks!